# vacuum breaker on hose bib (spigot)

Tags: plumbing, backflow-preventer

We have a backflow preventor on the water spigot in the garage.  A water hose is attached that has a sprayer on the end.  Every time we turn the water off from the hose and even with the sprayer left open and the water running, water shoots out everywhere onto the floor, walls, garage walk-through door, etc.  I know according to code that it has to be there but it is causing damage to the wall and trim in the garage.  Any recommendations or fixes?

Comment: How long does water shoot out for? Momentarily, or does it shoot out for an extended period of time?  Also, I take it we're talking drywall with a standard baseboard here?

Comment: Just until the pressure is released.  It is cinder block up appox 1 foot up with drywall and a decorative trim where the cinder block ends and the drywall begins.

Comment: Well, it may be broken.  Do you have freezes and if so, is it a sillcock?  Are you obeying the instructions on the sillcock regarding leaving hoses attached to it 24x7 and/or leaving the valve open 24x7 with shutoff at a manifold or hose?